# drawing outside client area, winAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing, client

How would I draw outside the client area of a window, and on the title bar. I know it can be done, but I am unsure of how to implement this effectively. Think google chrome, where the tabs are on the title bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Windows asks you to draw the portion of the window that is outside your client area, it will send you an [WM_NCPAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212(VS.85).aspx) message. Handle that message and draw whatever you want the non-client portion of your window to be. See the page I linked for an example of how to get a device context you can draw upon.

Comment: hmm, it seems to really mess up the drawing (mostly the menu). Is there something I'm missing? (I copied the example into my winProc and made it draw a rectangle.)

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth mentioning [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618(VS.85).aspx) also, if you plan on customizing where non-client elements are located.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing a custom window caption [DrawCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162476(VS.85).aspx)